# Can't use 'LIKE %' || My query didnt return all the row as i expected

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle, plsql

I have a query in c# (with Oracle command and Oracle parameters). I want to use the input that user entered when getting data from database.

This is my query:

```
SELECT USER_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
FROM USERS
WHERE USER_ID LIKE :userid || '%'  
  AND FIRSTNAME LIKE :firstname || '%'  
  AND LASTNAME LIKE :lastname || '%'
  AND DEPARTMENT LIKE :department || '%' 
  AND TEAM LIKE :team || '%'
  AND SUBTEAM LIKE :subteam || '%' 
  AND MACHINE LIKE :machine || '%'
```

User could be search entering just one input or all the inputs or none of the inputs.

Note: I've heard that, 'like%' doesn't work with the rows which has null column. But my database must has null columns. I need advice. What can I do?

Comment: You can use WHERE USER_ID LIKE '%'||:userid || '%'  .

Comment: @Mottor Same result. Still cant get the row which have null column. (I have a user who doesnt have machine and this query doesn get that row like mine)

Comment: WHERE (USER_ID LIKE '%'||:userid || '%'  or user_id is null)

Comment: `LIKE` always evaluates to `UNKNOWN` if either parameter is `NULL`. You have to use `IS NULL` to determine whether a column is null.

Comment: Hi Mr. @Kemp I tryed WHERE(USER_ID LIKE :userid || '%' OR :userid is null) AND (FIRSTNAME LIKE :firstname || '%' OR :firstname is null)... and i tryed empty inputs (it must be return all the users )but i have an error now. ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Comment: not :user_id is null but user_id is null. Without :

Comment: @Motto oh right it must be column name not the parameter. I'm going to try it

Comment: @Mottor Hey. U right i tryed and it works now. Thank u

Comment: Mr @Kemp Hi. I solved it and like u said the solution is using is null in query. If you can post it answer i can mark it. Maybe it help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved here is the solution ;

```
"SELECT USER_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM USERS WHERE (USER_ID LIKE :userid || '%' OR USER_ID IS NULL) AND (FIRSTNAME LIKE :firstname || '%' OR FIRSTNAME IS NULL) AND(LASTNAME LIKE :lastname || '%' OR LASTNAME IS NULL) AND (DEPARTMENT LIKE :department || '%' OR DEPARTMENT IS NULL) AND (TEAM LIKE :team || '%' OR TEAM IS NULL) AND (SUBTEAM LIKE :subteam || '%' OR SUBTEAM IS NULL) AND (MACHINE LIKE :machine || '%' OR MACHINE IS NULL)"
```

Answer (score 2):

For each parameter, if user input is given, the `LIKE` is evaluated. Otherwise user input `IS NULL`.

```
SELECT USER_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
FROM USERS
WHERE (USER_ID LIKE :userid || '%'  or :userid IS NULL)
  AND (FIRSTNAME LIKE :firstname || '%' or :firstname IS NULL)
  AND (LASTNAME LIKE :lastname || '%' or :lastname IS NULL)
  AND (DEPARTMENT LIKE :department || '%'  or :department IS NULL)
  AND (TEAM LIKE :team || '%' or :team IS NULL)
  AND (SUBTEAM LIKE :subteam || '%'  or :subteam IS NULL)
  AND (MACHINE LIKE :machine || '%' or :machine IS NULL)
```

Comment: I tryed it with all inputs emty. There is an error. ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Comment: "A SQL statement containing substitution variables was executed without all variables bound. All substitution variables must have a substituted value before the SQL statement is executed." http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01008_plsql_variables_bound.htm

Comment: Thats why i'm using 'like %' . I still dont know why it doesnt work

Answer (score -1):

If the user input is empty for missing value, try this

```
SELECT USER_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM USERS 
WHERE (USER_ID LIKE :userid || '%'  OR :userid='')
AND (FIRSTNAME LIKE :firstname || '%'    OR :firstname ='')
AND (LASTNAME LIKE :lastname || '%'   OR :lastname='')
AND (DEPARTMENT LIKE :department || '%'   OR :department='')
AND (TEAM LIKE :team || '%'   OR :team='')
AND (SUBTEAM LIKE :subteam || '%'   OR :subteam='')
AND (MACHINE LIKE :machine || '%'  OR :machine='')
```

Comment: Think that, i want to search users who in department qualty and in team A3. If i use or in query it gets the ALL QUALITY guys and ALL TEAM A3 guys. This is not i want to do. My and's are right. My problem is: This query doesnt select the rows which includes NULL column. I need that too

Comment: @Madhivanan: I think this is Oracle, so `= ''` needs to be `is null` (for the same reason that `like '%'` doesn't match null values).

Comment: This query wont work. Null is never = or <> something. Change it to is null.

Comment: @Madhivanan i tryed it with all inputs are empty. There is an error here; ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Comment: Mr. @Robertson hi. I tryed like you said -WHERE(USER_ID LIKE :userid || '%'  OR :userid is null)-  but there is same error here too. (ORA-01008: not all variables bound)

Comment: Mr @Robertson I solved it and like u said the solution is using is null in query. If you can post it answer i can mark it. Maybe it help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

Then maybe you could compare `NVL(..,'x')?`

```
SELECT USER_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM USERS 
 WHERE (nvl(USER_ID   ,'¬') LIKE nvl(:userid     , '¬')|| '%' )
   AND (nvl(FIRSTNAME ,'¬') LIKE nvl(:firstname  , '¬')|| '%' )
   AND (nvl(LASTNAME  ,'¬') LIKE nvl(:lastname   , '¬')|| '%' )
   AND (nvl(DEPARTMENT,'¬') LIKE nvl(:department , '¬')|| '%' )
   AND (nvl(TEAM      ,'¬') LIKE nvl(:team       , '¬')|| '%' )
   AND (nvl(SUBTEAM   ,'¬') LIKE nvl(:subteam    , '¬')|| '%' )
   AND (nvl(MACHINE   ,'¬') LIKE nvl(:machine    , '¬')|| '%' )
;
```

Comment: @Chomel Hi. Query works but like mine. It cant get that row which have null column. I need that

Comment: @Chomel I've got the solution now. I'm gonna add the solution as an answer. Thx for help